# How to create a dynamic link library in flutter like DLL in windows

Tags: flutter, package

How to create a dynamic link library in flutter like (DLL in windows)
when creating packages in a flutter it links statically in our code which produces big size executable file this is not suitable for a big application.
is there a way to create dynamic packages that load at run time like (DLL in windows)
Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like it would be very useful, especially for the purposes of GPL compliance (i.e. if a proprietary flutter app wants to use a library that is LGPL licensed, they would need to have a way for the end user to rebuild and swap the library out. if this requires rebuilding the proprietary app, then the proprietary app would also need to provide build scripts or other things (like build scripts or potentially even source code) to allow the users the freedom to replace the licensed library.